# Unable to Authenticate on Podio API using Access Token

Tags: oauth, podio

I am using oAuth Model to access Podio API. I am able to generate the Access Token and Refresh Token using a pair of Client ID and Client Secret. 
Later when i tried to authenticate using previously generated Access Token and Refresh Token with new pair of Client ID and Client Secret then getting Following Error Message:

{"{\"error_propagate\":false,\"error\":\"invalid_grant\",\"error_description\":\"Invalid refresh_token\",\"error_detail\":\"different_client_id\",\"request\":{\"url\":\"http://api.podio.com/oauth/token\",\"query_string\":\"\",\"method\":\"POST\"}}"}

When i tried to authenticate using same Pair of Client ID and Client secret that was originally used to generate the Access Token , it Works.

My Question is: Can we use different Client ID and Client Secret to authenticate through Access Tokens that were generated using different Client Id and Secret.

I hope i have clearly described my question.

Answer (score 2):

No, access tokens are tied to a specific client and secret. Allowing access tokens to be used with other clients would be a security hole.